# android:fontFamily doesn't work in styles.xml

Tags: android, custom-font

```
<style name="button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/button_height</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="cornerRadius">@dimen/button_round_radius</item>

    </style>
    <style name="button.wide" parent="button">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_regular</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
```

I do this in style file. but when I apply the style in layout. `style="@style/button.wide"`
the font doesn't work.

Comment: Your code worked in my case, there might be some other issue. where did you get cornerRadius?

Comment: cornerRadius is in dimen and it works fine

Comment: @QinxinZhang android:fontFamily works above api 26

Comment: @QinxinZhang android:fontFamily works above api 26

Answer (score 0):

try using `android:theme="@style/button.wide"`

Comment: I think you should add more details in your answer.

Comment: could you please be more specific?

Comment: i don't know exactly answer but it working in my project

Answer (score 0):

Change button style name and parent like, name="ButtonViewStyle" 
and parent="android:Widget.Button"

```
<style name="ButtonViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_regular</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

Use `<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonViewStyle</item>` line to your parent style

```
   <style name="button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/button_height</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="cornerRadius">@dimen/button_round_radius</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonViewStyle</item>
    </style>
```